# Google Chrome and Chromium closes after few seconds what to do

Tags: google-chrome, xfce, chromium, browser

I am using latest version of Ubuntu 20.04 with XFCE4 desktop environment. I've used chromium for several days and after some time chromium start to close after few seconds of execution. After that I've installed Google Chrome, and after some days, the same problem occurs.

This is the error when I launch Chrome and Chromium with terminal:

```
[0725/065734.139865:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a 

sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

What to do please help me.

Comment: I came across [this](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/issues/176#issuecomment-160497289) while looking around to see if others had your error.

Comment: firejail google-chrome and firejail google-chrome --no-sandbox
didn't worked for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a problem in `.config` and `.cache` folder where Chrome's detailed folder is located.

I fixed it by deleting files named `google-chrome-stable` in `~/.cache` and `~/.config` and reinstalling Google Chrome.

I wrote up my solution here [Google Chrome closes after a few seconds](https://blog.webmatrices.com/google-chrome-closes-itself-automatically).

Comment: Please do not send the same [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1262563/264781) to different questions. Per policy, we've removed the duplicates and left the first of your answers intact. If the questions all discuss the same thing, once you had enough reputation it would be better to flag the questions as duplicates of one of the questions rather than post the same answer numerous times.

Comment: You posted 2 answers. as Ravexina said, promoting the same site. That makes these answers look like spam. If you are affiliated (which does strongly appear to be the case), you *must disclose that affiliation in the post*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).

Comment: This is a SPAM link. Please delete